# Confiar en un solo certificado TLS/SSL con Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, certificado-ssl, tls

He realizado un escaneo dinamico DAST usando appScan, y este me dice que tengo en mi codigo fuente un método que confia en todos los certificados que disminuye la capa de seguridad establecida con TLS, pueden apoyarme en decirme como modificar mi método usando Spring Boot, si bienconsidero que es en el `HostNameVerifier` donde tengo el detalle, pudieran apoyarme diciendome como realizo la correccion, para este caso uso Spring Boot Boot 2.0.0 release

```
    @Configuration
public class ConfiguracionSSL {
    
        private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

        @Value("${http.client.ssl.trust-store}")
        private Resource trustStore;

        @Value("${http.client.ssl.trust-store-password}")
        private char[] trustStorePassword;

        @Bean
        public ClientHttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory() {
            return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient());
        }

        @Bean
        public HttpClient httpClient() {

            Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = null;
            try {
                SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts
                        .custom()
                        .loadTrustMaterial(trustStore.getFile(),
                                trustStorePassword)
                        .build();
               sslContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2"); 
               
                SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext,
                        new HostnameVerifier() {

                            @Override
                            public boolean verify(final String hostname,
                                    final SSLSession session) {
                                return true;
                            }
                });

                socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
                        .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory())
                        .register("https", sslSocketFactory)
                        .build();           

            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Error inesperado", e);
            }

            PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(socketFactoryRegistry);
            return HttpClientBuilder.create()
                    .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
                    .disableCookieManagement()
                    .disableAuthCaching()
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean
        public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.setRequestFactory(httpRequestFactory());
            return restTemplate;
        }    
        
        
        

}
```